# kill the specific Excel.exe from the .vbs file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am running a .vbs script to kill excel and wscript from the task manager. Below is my script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, colProcess2

'KILL EXCEL IN TASK MANAGER
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & "'EXCEL.EXE'")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
    Call CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("taskkill /f /im Excel.exe", 0, True)
Next

'KILL vbs IN TASK MANAGER
Set colProcess2 = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & "'wscript.exe'")
For Each objProcess in colProcess2
    Call CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("taskkill /f /im wscript.exe", 0, True)
Next

WScript.Quit
```

The script is running successfully to kill the excel and script. But can I kill the specific excel report, instead of killing all the excel in the server? For example, I want to kill aaa.xlsx and this excel can be found on resource manager:
[image]

Is there a way to kill the specific excel using vbs script?

Comment: You don't need to use `taskkill.exe` because `Win32_Process` has a `Terminate(reason)` method already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/terminate-method-in-class-win32-process

Comment: WMI does not expose open handles to files on-disk, so you'll need to use another command-line utility such as Microsoft's Sysinternals `handles.exe` ( https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-process-locked-file-openfiles-utility/ ) and pipe that into your VBScript - or do it all from a single batch file.

Comment: I think the big picture needs to be considered here.. how did you get to this situation of needing to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Jobbo in the server we encounter excel (aaa.xlsx) is open and we have check all the remote login is not opening this excel and this excel-folder is not shared. Since we know the excel name, I would like to kill this excel, instead of kill "EXCEL.exe" in the server.